# Accessing parent `this` from object setter

Tags: javascript, object, this, getter-setter

How can you access a parent context from a setter in an object?

In the following example, imagine I need the variable `Foo.other` to compute the `state.bar` setter. How would you go about achieving that?

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.other = 'i am an other variable'
        this.state = {
            _bar: 'default',
            set bar(flag) {
                console.log() // how can I access foo.other from here?
                this._bar = flag
            },
            get bar() {
                return this._bar
            }
        }
    }
}

const foo = new Foo()
foo.state.bar = 'yolo'
```

Comment: In react, getters and setters inside of the state are cleared when setState is called.

Comment: @Kobe this isn't react though.

Comment: Ah okay, just seemed similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` returns a pointer to the current object. You can store that reference in a variable and then use that variable to retrieve the old `this` object when the scope has been changed. Most common names for such variables are `self`, `_this`, `_self`, `me` and `_me`.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    var self = this;
    this.other = 'i am an other variable';
    this.state = {
      _bar: 'default',
      set bar(flag) {
        console.log(self.other);
        this._bar = flag;
      },
      get bar() {
        return this._bar;
      }
    }
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.state.bar = 'yolo';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a bit disappointing that there isn't a "cleaner" way to do this. Couldn't I do something like bind `state` to the `this` of Foo (and yes, I'd have to call `this.state._bar` in that case for the getter/setter).

Comment: @Sheraff That would require a lot of changes, since you can't bind an es6 `get` or `set`, you would have to use `Object.defineProperty`. I doubt that you would find that way cleaner. using `self` is the cleaner and most popular way to deal with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `this` inside the setter, you refer to the `state` object that does not have an `other` property defined (Check the second console.log that refers to `this._bar`).

You can store `this` to a variable (self) like this:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        const self = this;
        this.other = 'i am an other variable'
        this.state = {
            _bar: 'default',
            set bar(flag) {
                console.log(self.other);
                console.log(this._bar);
                this._bar = flag
            },
            get bar() {
                return this._bar
            }
        }
    }
}

const foo = new Foo()
foo.state.bar = 'yolo'
```